# Expo SDK43 "AndroidCheckBox" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: expo, android-checkbox, react-native-community

After upgrading to expo SDK 43, I am getting this error on Android:

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "AndroidCheckBox" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in AndroidCheckBox (created by CheckBox)
    in CheckBox
    in CheckBoxWithRef (at SimpleCheckbox.js:18)    <-- custom component
    in SimpleCheckbox (at LoginScreen.js:76)        <-- custom component
```

I am using `"@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.9"`, on the managed workflow.

I tried to run `expo install @react-native-community/checkbox` because I saw other posts solving their own "not found in the UIManager" errors this way, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fixed it by replacing `@react-native-community/checkbox` with `expo-checkbox`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by;

- First install **expo-checkbox** by running `$ npm i expo-checkbox -f`
- Then, import `CheckBox` at the top of your file like so; `import CheckBox from 'expo-checkbox';`

Then, use the `CheckBox` like so:

```js
interface IProps {
  checked?: boolean;
  value?: boolean | undefined;
  onValueChange?: ((value: boolean) => void) | undefined

}


export const ReferAndEarnInputCheckBox: React.FC<IProps> = () => {
  const [toggleCheckBox, setToggleCheckBox] = useState(false)



  return (

    <CheckBox
      disabled={false}
      value={toggleCheckBox}
      onValueChange={(newValue) => setToggleCheckBox(newValue)
      }
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and fixed it by changing the **expo version to 42** or build your project by running the command **npm run android**.
It works in my case.
https://github.com/react-native-checkbox/react-native-checkbox/issues/144

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and fixed it by changing the expo version to 42 or build your project by running the command npm run android. It works in my case. https://github.com/react-native-checkbox/react-native-checkbox/issues/144
/// work ,,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).